# Mongo Super User won't connect to another database other than admin

Tags: mongodb

Why is that?

```
$ mongo admin -u admin -p password --host 192.168.99.100
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: 192.168.99.100:27017/admin
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
> db^C
bye
cesco@laptop: ~/code/go/src/bitbucket.org/cescoferraro/cluster/containers on develop [!$]
$ mongo iot -u admin -p password --host 192.168.99.100
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: 192.168.99.100:27017/iot
2016-09-25T22:22:36.829-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Answer (score 5):

Although the `admin` user you've created has global permissions through *AnyDatabase roles, the user credentials only exist in the `admin` database. As per your example, you will fail to authenticate if matching user credentials don't exist in the database you are trying to access.

To authenticate with the `mongo` shell using credentials stored in a different database from the one which you are trying to access (`admin` vs `iot`) you can either:

1) Specify the database with user credentials using `--authenticationDatabase`:

```
 mongo iot --authenticationDatabase admin -u admin -p password --host 192.168.99.100
```

2) Specify the default database as `/admin` and then change to the desired target database:

```
 $ mongo -u admin -p password 192.168.99.100/admin

 MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
 connecting to: 192.168.99.100/admin

 > use iot
 switched to db iot
```

The first example is the most typical approach.

NOTE: If you want to specify host and database as per the second example, you have to provide the database connection string without using the `--host` parameter.